# Правильность пунктуации

Tags: пунктуация

Правильно ли расставлены знаки препинания?

> Назовите клиенту адрес энной почты, если он указан ниже, и уточните у клиента верен ли этот адрес. Если адрес не указан, то попросите клиента продиктовать его.

Comment: Вы робот? В чём проблема, где знак вопроса?

Comment: Нет, не робот) Интересует правильность проставления знаков препинания в указанном предложении

Comment: Что такое "энная почта"? Неужели электронная почта теперь так сокращется? Вообще-то энный - некий, некоторый, любой [по обозначению латинской буквой N, n, Primo в формулах] Пример: Энное число. Энная сумма.

Answer (score 1):

> Назовите клиенту адрес энной почты, если он указан ниже, и уточните у клиента верен ли этот адрес. Если адрес не указан, то попросите клиента продиктовать его.

С точки зрения **только** пунктуации, нужно добавить одну запятую:

**Назовите клиенту адрес энной почты, если он указан ниже, и уточните у клиента, верен ли этот адрес. Если адрес не указан, то попросите клиента продиктовать его.**

---

Что такое "энная почта"? Неужели электронная почта теперь так сокращется? Вообще-то энный - некий, некоторый, любой [по обозначению латинской буквой N, n, Primo в формулах] Пример: Энное число. Энная сумма.

Comment: А почему перед "если" нужна запятая?

Comment: "Назовите клиенту адрес ... почты, если он указан ниже." Запятая ставится, так как это слож­но­под­чи­нен­ное пред­ло­же­ние с обсто­я­тель­ствен­ным при­да­точным со зна­че­ни­ем усло­вия. Уточ­ня­ет­ся усло­вие, при кото­ром про­те­ка­ет или может про­те­кать дей­ствие, о кото­ром гово­рит­ся в глав­ном пред­ло­же­нии. Придаточное усло­вия зави­сит от глав­но­го пред­ло­же­ния и отве­ча­ет на вопрос "при каком усло­вии?" Оно при­со­еди­ня­ет­ся к глав­но­му с помо­щью под­чи­ни­тель­ного союза *если*.